# Difference between OpenGL ES3 and ES2 shader variables

Tags: opengl-es-3.0

For OpenGL ES 3.0, I am wondering if we still use `attribute`/`varying` etc for variables. or we need to switch to `in`/`out` variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch to `in`/`out` if you move to the new GLSL version (`#version 300 es`). The spec documents the new storage qualifiers, and also specifically mentions:

> When porting applications from OpenGL ES 2.0 to OpenGL ES 3.0, the following points should be noted: Not all language constructs present in v1.00 of the language are available in v3.00 e.g. attribute and varying qualifiers. However, the functionality of GLSL ES 3.00 is a super-set of  GLSL ES 1.00.